# How do I make a variable accessible by multiple computers?

Tags: html, variables, web, button

I want to make a website where people on different computers can click on a button, and a counter below will show the total times the button has been clicked by everyone on the website, and the counter automatically refreshes. I also would like for each person that clicks to be able to make a username for a leaderboard that updates by itself, but I don't know where to start.

I tried researching this but it is kind of hard to find the correct answer because I'm not quite sure what the  correct question is

Comment: The reason there isn't a correct answer is because this isn't one question, it's at least several. To build something like this you'd need a central location to store the data, and you'd probably want to use websockets to communicate  changes to and from that central store.

Answer (score 0):

You could use nodejs and try something like this in order to have it get saved to a file. For the leaderboard system, you'd probably want to get user's IPs but I'm not exactly sure how to do that while keeping your users' information private. I'd recommend looking into mySQL for the leaderboard part but the code below should help get you started. Good luck

```
<script>
var clicks = require("./holderFile.json").clicks
const fs = require("fs")

function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  let data = {"clicks": clicks}
  fs.writeFile("./holderFile.json", JSON.stringify(data).replaceAll("\\",""), function(err){if(err){console.log(err)}})
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
</script>
<button type="button" onClick="onClick()">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```